# Recyclerview pushing up actionbar but with sticky header

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-recyclerview, sticky

In my Android app I have screen with a RecyclerView. I managed that the actionbar above it scrolls up whenever the RecyclerView is scrolled up (by the same amount of movement). I managed to do so with a CoordinatorLayout, an AppBarLayout and a ToolBar.

After this action bar is hidden now I want a header be sticky. How this can be achieved? See a sample, as this for example is realized by the Youtube app (Note that I want this to work for any layout, not only tabs as in the Youtube app):

[image: Scroll up actionbar with sticky header].

Comment: In the gif picture you give, you can put `TabLayout` in `AppBarLayout` and don't set its `layout_scrollFlags`(so that it won't scroll). It's the same if you use other layout other than `TabLayout`.

Comment: @LymZoy You are totally right. This is the correct answer. The solution is two place two layouts inside the AppBarlayout. The toolbar and the custom layout with app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap".

Answer (score 0):

you can see this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/scrolling-techniques-for-material-design--cms-24435) for different scrolling techniques.

Comment: Thanks, but the sample only works with a sticky TabLayout as you see it in the youtube video as well by calling tab_layout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);. But I want this to work with any Layout...